# I have a content type that has an integer field, but I can't find the table for that field in the database, what gives?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I'm working on a project inherited from another developer. One of the content types has an Integer field and I wanted to do a custom query that checked the value of this fields. When I went looking in the database I couldn't find the associated table.

The field is **field_company_upgraded** in the content type editor so I was expecting to see a **field_data_field_company_upgraded** table, but it didn't exist. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that the site in question isn't using SQL as the field storage backend. Can you confirm that the storage backend is definitely SQL?

Comment: It is, BUT it also uses a MongoDB plugin, which is primarily used for caching. MongoDB might be storing the upgraded value though as I could see it being related to caching.

Comment: That sounds pretty likely...if you can't find that table in the SQL database, and you're not getting errors when accessing that field, it must be getting the data from somewhere else